# MySQL select column if it exists

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

I've made the following query but when I try selecting one more column I dont get any result. I just cant figure out how to select that column (the if statement is the one in question) .

The thing is that `sub_acc` column in the `cash_payment_detail` table can also be `null`. Any help would mean a lot. Please note that I'm still learning.

```
SELECT
     LPAD(cash_payments_detail.`control_acc`,5,0) AS Control_Account,
     CAccountDescription As Control_Account_Name,
     LPAD(cash_payments_detail.`sub_acc`,4,0) AS Sub_Account,
     **if (coasub.`SAccountNo` = cash_payments_detail.`sub_acc`, coasub.`SAccountDescription`," ") As Sub_Account_Name**
FROM
    coasub, coacontrol, `cash_payments_detail` cash_payments_detail INNER JOIN `cash_payments` cash_payments ON cash_payments_detail.`cpvno` = cash_payments.`cpvno`
WHERE
control_acc = coacontrol.`CAccountNo`
```

Comment: The bold (**) column doesn't show in your query.

Comment: whoops sorry, its the one with the **, the if statement

Comment: 1) You have to use `OUTER JOIN` e.g. `LEFT JOIN` 2) Don't mix comma style and ANSI style `JOIN`s

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, could not have figured it out with you.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the join you did you have to learn the joins well before writing such queries and notice that the join you wrote doesn't return records when 
cash_payment_detail.sub_acc is null 
the left join will return the null values ;)
use the **left Join** instead of **inner join**...
try this query:

```
SELECT
cash_payments.cpvno AS Voucher_Number, date_format(cash_payments.vdate,'%d %M %Y') AS Voucher_Date,
sec_users.name AS Entered_By, cash_payments.payto AS Payment_To, cash_payments.payref AS On_Account_Of, LPAD(cash_payments.branch,5,0) AS Cash_Control_Account, branches.cash_control_name AS Cash_Control_Name,
branches.name AS Branch_Name,
LPAD(cash_payments_detail.control_acc,5,0) AS Control_Account, CAccountDescription As Control_Account_Name,
LPAD(cash_payments_detail.sub_acc,4,0) AS Sub_Account, if (SAccountNo = sub_acc, SAccountDescription," ") As Sub_Account_Name,
cash_payments_detail.job_no AS Job, cash_payments_detail.narration AS Narration, cash_payments_detail.debit AS Debit
FROM
coasub, coacontrol, branches, sec_users, cash_payments_detail cash_payments_detail 
LEFT JOIN cash_payments cash_payments ON cash_payments_detail.cpvno = cash_payments.cpvno 
WHERE
control_acc = coacontrol.CAccountNo AND cashcontrol = cash_payments.branch AND cash_payments.login = sec_users.login
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it. I tried the left join and even removed the join altogether and used the where clause but no luck EDIT: Nevermind I figured it out, mixed up the joins. Thanks for help.